# Firebase Android Phone Authentication verification code is wrong error

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments, firebase-authentication

I'm quite new to kotlin so i need your help. I m trying to create a firebase phone authentication system, the following code snippets the idea that i followed. When i enter the phone number i recieve the verification code. However, when i enter the verification code, sign in fails and i got the verification code is not correct error even though the code is completely same that i recieved.

I m not sure what i m missing. I would be appriciated if someone could help me, thanks in advance!

Here is the login func in login fragment:

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login_screen, container, false)
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog(context)
        progressDialog.setTitle("Please Wait")
        progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)


        var currentUser = auth.currentUser
        if(currentUser != null) {
            val intent = Intent(context, ProfileActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        callbacks = object : PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

            override fun onVerificationCompleted(phoneAuthCredential: PhoneAuthCredential) {
                val intent = Intent(context, ProfileActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            }

            override fun onVerificationFailed(e: FirebaseException) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }

            override fun onCodeSent(
                verificationId: String,
                token: PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken
            ) {

                Log.d("TAG","onCodeSent:$verificationId")
                Log.d("TAG","Verification code:, $verificationId");
                storedVerificationId = verificationId
                resendToken = token
                Toast.makeText(context,"Kod gönderiliyor",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                val action = LoginScreenDirections.actionLoginScreen2ToVerificationScreen()
                Navigation.findNavController(requireView()).navigate(action)
            }
        }

        return view
    }

    private fun login() {
        val mobileNumber=requireView().findViewById<EditText>(R.id.phoneNumber)
        var number=mobileNumber.text.toString().trim()

        if(!number.isEmpty()){
            number="+90"+number
            sendVerificationcode (number)

        }else{
            Toast.makeText(context,"Enter mobile number",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }

    private fun sendVerificationcode(number: String) {
        progressDialog.setMessage("Verifying Phone Number..")
        progressDialog.dismiss()
        val options = PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(auth)
            .setPhoneNumber(number) // Phone number to verify
            .setTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // Timeout and unit
            .setActivity(requireActivity()) // Activity (for callback binding)
            .setCallbacks(callbacks) // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
            .build()
        PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options)

    }
```

Here is the verification screen:

```
class VerificationScreen : Fragment() {

    lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_verification_screen, container, false)

        return view
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        auth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

        val storedVerificationId: String? = null

//        Reference
        val verify=requireView().findViewById<Button>(R.id.verifyBtn)
        val otpGiven=requireView().findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextNumber)


        verify.setOnClickListener{
            val otp=otpGiven.text.toString().trim()
            if(!otp.isEmpty()){
                var credential : PhoneAuthCredential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
                    storedVerificationId.toString(), otp)
                signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential)
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(context,"Enter OTP",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }

    }
    private fun signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential: PhoneAuthCredential) {
        auth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener {
                Toast.makeText(context,"Enter OTP",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                if (it.isSuccessful){
                    Toast.makeText(context,"Başardın",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                   /* val intent = Intent(context, ProfileActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)*/
                } else{
                    // Sign in failed, display a message and update the UI
                    if (it.exception is FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                    // The verification code entered was invalid
                        Toast.makeText(context,"Invalid OTP",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **300 (three hundred)** lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: *storedVerificationId* in second screen is null, so you must send it from previous screen via intent argument, which you get inside 'onCodeSent()' method.